# VB.net SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have two columns that I need to return the count of usernames by date

```
DateOnly              Username
 12/01/2014 00:00:00    Dave
 12/01/2014 00:00:00    Bob
 12/01/2014 00:00:00    Steve
 12/01/2014 00:00:00    Richard
 13/01/2014 00:00:00    Dave
 13/01/2014 00:00:00    Dave
 13/01/2014 00:00:00    Bob
 14/01/2014 00:00:00    Dave
```

And so on, will always have around 2000 - 3000 records per day.

I want to display it like

```
Username          12/01/2014            13/01/2014         14/01/2014
Dave                 1                       2                 1
Bob                  1                       1                 0
Steve                1                       0                 0
Richard              1                       0                 0
```

I want the user to select two dates to search between i.e. `WHERE = 12/01/2014 and 14/01/2014`

So I don't know how many columns there will be.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to first write the query with your limited number of dates, so you can get the logic correct for the PIVOT query.

When you have a limited number of values, then you can easily hard-code the query:

```
select username,
  [2014-01-12], [2014-01-13], [2014-01-14]
from
(
  select username, dateonly
  from yourtable
  where dateonly >= '2014-01-12'
    and dateonly <= '2014-01-14'
) d
pivot
(
  count(dateonly)
  for dateonly in ([2014-01-12], [2014-01-13], [2014-01-14])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c6e7/6).

Once you have the logic down, then you can create a dynamic SQL version of the query.  Since you will have an unknown dates, then I would create a calendar table that contains dates that will be used to create the final column values.

For example, you can create a table like:

```
create table dates
(
  dt datetime
);
insert into dates
values
('2014-01-01'), ('2014-01-02'), ('2014-01-03'),
('2014-01-04'), ('2014-01-05'), ('2014-01-06'),
('2014-01-07'), ('2014-01-08'), ('2014-01-09'),
('2014-01-10'), ('2014-01-11'), ('2014-01-12'),
('2014-01-13'), ('2014-01-14'), ('2014-01-15');
```

This table will then be used to create your dynamic columns.  The dynamic SQL version of this will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@startdt datetime, @enddt datetime'

-- these values would be passed into your stored procedure
set @startdate = '2014-01-10'
set @enddate = '2014-01-14'

-- this creates the list of final columns to be displayed using the 
-- dates table.  Using the calendar table makes sure that you return all dates you
-- requested even if you do not have those values in DateOnly
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), dt, 120)) 
                    from dates
                    where dt >= @startdate
                      and dt <= @enddate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT username, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select username, dateonly
              from yourtable
              where dateonly >= @startdt
                and dateonly <= @enddt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(dateonly)
                for dateonly in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query, 
  @ParmDefinition,
  @startdt = @startdate,
  @enddt = @enddate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c6e7/6). Both versions give a result:

```
| USERNAME | 2014-01-10 | 2014-01-11 | 2014-01-12 | 2014-01-13 | 2014-01-14 |
|----------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|      Bob |          0 |          0 |          1 |          1 |          0 |
|     Dave |          0 |          0 |          1 |          2 |          1 |
|  Richard |          0 |          0 |          1 |          0 |          0 |
|    Steve |          0 |          0 |          1 |          0 |          0 |
```